# Sublime regex change \n to space if followed by lower case

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I know this sounds like a repeated question, but I'm relatively new to Regex and don't really understand some of the other answers. I managed to get this to work previously with something like

```
Find: \n+[(a-z)] 
Replace: *space*\1
```

I can't remember the exact terms I used though, and now if I try it the subsequent alphabet is deleted, and online regex testers say the \1 in replace is an invalid expression.

E.g.

```
I 
want
this
To remove
Newlines
```

should become

```
I want this 
To remove
Newlines
```

but is instead becoming

```
I ant his
To remove
Newlines
```

I don't remember what I used the first time round, but i disabled the "whole word" option in sublime, and somehow managed to remove the newlines without cutting characters. Why is \1 invalid? also what is the difference whether I use "+" or not? I don't really understand what greedy means. Sorry, and thank you!

Edit: thanks for all the responses! I definitely have a lot more to learn about using regex more flexibly, but in this case it was the difference between [(a-z)] and ([a-z]) that I missed.

Comment: `[(a-z)]` is a character class for opening and closing parenthesis and lowercase letters. `([a-z])` is a capturing group (that can be referenced by `\groupnumber`) containing a character class for lowercase letters.

Comment: Thank you!!! This was the thing I missed out on

Comment: @cobaltB12: Please consider upvoting the answer(s) that proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you reached 15 rep points and have the upvoting privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like

```
(?: )?[\n\r]([a-z])
```

And replace the occurence with `$1` (space, followed by `$1`), see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FwqdxJ/1).

---

Explanation:

```
(?: )?  # Looks for a space, this is optional
[\n\r]  # newline
([a-z]) # a character between a and z, lowercase
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not contain a *capturing group*. A `\1` in the replacement pattern is a *backreference* to the capture group inside the regex pattern. If the group does not exist, the error pops up.

You seem to want to replace 1+ line breaks before a lowercase letter. Make sure your settings are like this:

The regex is: `\h*\R+([a-z])` (where `\h*` matches 0+ horizontal whitespaces, `\R+` matches *any* 1+ line breaks, `CRLF/LF/CR` and `([a-z])` matches a lowercase ASCII letter)
Replacement:  `\1` (where `\1` puts back Group 1 value)

Settings:

[image]

Note that the case sensitivity must be enabled, too.

Comment: This [**leaves too many spaces**](https://regex101.com/r/FwqdxJ/2), ie between `I` and `want`.

Comment: Do you mean the space after `I`? Just adding `\h*` will fix it.

Comment: But you'll soon land at my expression then :)